Landlord went most of last year without asking me to sign a lease, then send me a back-dated lease without a signature date. Can I refuse to sign?
The title mostly covers it.   The lease mentions the period (now passed, at the time nearly passed), July 2023-June 2024 but it doesn't have a date of signature line.
If I sign this lease, it will look like he sent it to me on time not 10 months late.   The lease locks me in for the next 12 months and I think that's why the landlord waited so long to ask me to renew, because he was hoping I wouldn't catch that in the language.
I've not signed it, and I find it difficult to believe what the landlord is doing is legal, but I can't prove he sent it to me 10 months late.   At this point, I'm going to move out, and the landlord is using a threatening tone with me, as if I'm the one in the wrong.
Can I tell the landlord that he broke the law, or is this a grey area.   I know that laws vary by state.   New Jersey if that matters.
I might hire a lawyer if this keeps up, but for now, I'm just asking the laws on sending me a back dated lease with no date of signature.
Edit, I put this in a comment below but I'll add it here because it clarifies the question:
The landlord put a clause in the lease (offer) which basically says "on July 1 2024, a new 12 months rental agreement is triggered" - not in those words, but that was the meaning.
That kind of language is probably legal, though it's dirty since he tried to hide it in legalese and he asked me to sign that document 2 weeks before it would have triggered.
The landlord not only asked me to sign (asked me to sign the day he dropped it off while he waited), but later, yelled at me for not signing.
Since I didn't sign, it's a little bit moot. But I was mostly wondering, and this is the gist of the question, if the landlord broke any laws in the way he tried to get me to sign in June 2024 when the document covers the period July 2023 till June 30, 2024.

I think this should be answerable without breaking the rule about legal advice. Does NJ have any laws about what counts as a lease in the absence of a signed document? Does a lease exist? Are there any presumed rights in the absence of a document?

Right now that document is merely an offer of a lease, not an actual lease, because you haven't agreed to it. You could simply write back with a counter-offer. Were you promised anything verbally? If so, write back saying that as far as you are concerned the lease terms are what you were promised verbally. Then list them.

@PaulJohnson the issue seems to be around the attempt to back date the contract which should be unrelated to the rest of the contract.

@JoeW That's why I didn't write an answer. I don't know NJ rental law. The landlord seems to be trying to get the OP to give up a strong position, so its reasonable to suggest that the OP should not get railroaded regardless of any specific NJ law about having a written lease.

@PaulJohnson I think that is the reason that it is attracting close votes

"I can't prove he sent it to me 10 months late": he can't prove you signed it ten months ago, nor that he sent it to you ten months ago without your signing it.  But if it mentions the period ending June 2024, how does it lock you in for the next 12 months?

@PaulJohnson as I've read and understood it (not a lawyer), New Jersey law basically keeps the original lease's clauses in effect, but without a new signed agreement, goes into a month-to-month situation.   So all the original clauses still apply.    One of the problems is that this landlord has regularly re-written the lease (offer) and yelled at me for not signing it though there are clauses that I'd be crazy to sign.    This question was about the back-dating, which is somewhat complicated legally.  I've tried to look it up but it's not been clear to me.

@PaulJohnson the rest of the lease offer had issues too, but I've written him about that and asked him to remove those paragraphs.

@phoog  the landlord put a clause in that basically says "on July 1, a new 12 months rental agreement is triggered" - not in those words, but that was the meaning.    That kind of language is probably legal, though it's dirty since he tried to hide it in legalese and he asked me to sign that document 2 weeks before it would have triggered.   Not only asked, but yelled at me for not signing it.     Since I didn't sign, that's kind of moot.   But I was mostly wondering if he broke any laws in the way he tried to get me to sign in June 2024 a document that begins coverage in July 2023.

Deliberately signing a backdated contract can amount to fraud and/or forgery.
There is nothing wrong with retrospective contracts per se. But the contract should be clear that that is what it is. The correct way is for it to be dated on the date that the agreement was actually reached (e.g. today) but to state that the rights and obligations apply to a specified period which is in the past. The wrong way is to date it from the beginning of the period and pretend that that is when the agreement was reached.
It's also worth bearing in mind that if a landlord has allowed a tenant to take occupation of a rental property, then there is already a contract. It's just a contract agreed orally and/or by conduct rather than in writing. Depending on the jurisdiction such contracts may have certain implied terms via legislation.
Retrospective contracts should, if well drafted, be explicit that the parties agree that the new written terms are to replace any previous non-written terms (where such exist).
We can't give you legal advice so you'll need to decide what you think is the best course of action. If you want legal advice you should consider hiring a lawyer.
